# Trying to import data from a SQL query but getting error [Teradata Database] [3810] Column/Parameter 'ods_vw_gb_db_q.hist.os_inv_num' does not exist."

Tags: sql, parameters, powerbi, teradata, data-analysis

```
   select bat.\* from (select
    "Processing Mode ", "Registration Number",  "AUN",  "Tracking Number",  "Invoice Number",
    "Invoice Item", "Invoice Date", "Sales Ord Number", "SO Line Item",
    "Sold to Number",   "Sold to Name", 
    "Entering Branch",  "Ship Date",    "Part Number",  "Neda Number",  "Quantity Ordered", "Quantity Shipped",
    "Unit Price",   "Unit Cost",
    "User ID",  "GBC AUN",  "SendingRegion",    "SupplierAssignedSoldTo",
    "OSShiptoCountry",  "Country",  "SupplierAssignedShipTo",
    "OffshoreRegion",   "OffshoreCurrency", "RcvRegionItem",    "RcvRegionCorePart",    "SendingRegionCorePart"
    
    from (Select
    reg.registration_num
    AS "Registration Number",
    reg.tracking_num
    AS "Tracking Number",
    reg.internal_dwr_num
    AS "AUN",
    
           msi.segment3
               AS "Part Number",
           CASE
               WHEN reg.ssid = 5 THEN 'AC'
               WHEN reg.ssid = 9 THEN 'AP'
               WHEN reg.ssid = 2 THEN 'EU'
           END
               AS "SendingRegion",
           msi.DSWG_154_CORE_PART
               AS SendingRegionCorePart,
                 CASE
               WHEN reg.ssid = 5 THEN 'ACGBC'
               WHEN reg.ssid = 9 THEN 'APGBC'
               WHEN reg.ssid = 2 THEN 'EUGBC'
           END
              as snd_gbc_region
               from ods_vw_gb_db_q.dsw_regstrations       reg,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.dsw_boards             board,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.dsw_projects           proj,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.mtl_system_items       msi
            WHERE     board.dsw_boards_skey = reg.dsw_boards_skey
            AND proj.dsw_projects_skey = board.dsw_projects_skey
           AND reg.mtl_system_items_skey = msi.mtl_system_items_skey) snd,
           (select  CASE WHEN soli.unit_selling_price > 0 THEN 'ADD' ELSE 'SUB' END
               AS "Processing Mode",    ih.trx_number
               AS "Invoice Number",
           ili.line_number
               AS "Invoice Item",
           ih.trx_date
               AS "Invoice Date",
           soh.order_number
               AS "Sales Ord Number",
           soli.global_attribute1
               AS "SO Line Item",
           billto1.site_use_id
               AS "Sold to Number",
           billto1.account_name
               AS "Sold to Name",
           so.seb_name
               AS "Entering Branch",
           soli.IVH_SALES_DATE
               AS "Ship Date",
           '9999'
               AS "Neda Number",
           soli.ordered_quantity
               AS "Quantity Ordered",
           soli.shipped_quantity
               AS "Quantity Shipped",
           soli.unit_selling_price
               AS "Unit Price",
           soli.attribute3
               AS "Unit Cost",
           NULL
               AS "User ID",
           reg1.internal_dwr_id
               AS "GBC AUN",
           
           NULL
               AS SupplierAssignedSoldTo,
           NULL
               AS OSShiptoCountry,
           NULL
               AS Country,
           NULL
               AS SupplierAssignedShipTo,
           CASE
               WHEN reg1.ssid = 5 THEN 'AC'
               WHEN reg1.ssid = 9 THEN 'AP'
               WHEN reg1.ssid = 2 THEN 'EU'
           END
               AS OffshoreRegion,
          inv.attribute15
               AS OffshoreCurrency,
           msi1.segment3
               AS RcvRegionItem,
           msi1.DSWG_154_CORE_PART
               AS RcvRegionCorePart,
               reg1.ATTRIBUTE3 as rcv_attribute3,
               reg1.ssid as rcv_ssid
           from ods_vw_gb_db_q.dsw_inv_hist           inv,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.dsw_regstrations       reg1,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.INVOICE_LINE_ITEM      ili,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.INVOICE_HEADER         ih,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.sales_order_line_item  soli,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.sales_order_header     soh,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.customer_bill_to       billto1,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.sales_organization     so,
           ods_vw_gb_db_q.mtl_system_items       msi1,
           ods_vw_ac_db_q.time_period_date tpd,
           ods_vw_ac_db_q.time_period_date tpd1
           where 1=1
           AND reg1.dsw_regstrations_skey = inv.dsw_regstrations_skey
           AND inv.invoice_line_item_skey = ili.invoice_line_item_skey
           AND IH.INVOICE_HEADER_SKEY = ILi.INVOICE_HEADER_SKEY
           AND SoH.SALES_ORDER_HEADER_SKEY = Soli.SALES_ORDER_HEADER_SKEY
           AND ili.sales_order_line_item_skey = soli.sales_order_line_item_skey
           AND soli.customer_bill_to_skey = billto1.customer_bill_to_skey
           AND soli.sales_entering_branch_skey = so.sales_entering_branch_skey
           AND reg1.mtl_system_items_skey = msi1.mtl_system_items_skey
           and reg1.attribute3 not like '%RCV%'
           and ih.trx_date = tpd1.time_period_date
           and current_date = tpd.time_period_date
           and tpd1.relative_global_year = 0
           and tpd1.relative_global_year  >= 
          case when tpd.relative_global_month = 0 and tpd.fiscal_month_mmm = 'JAN' 
           then -1
           when tpd.relative_global_month = 0 and tpd.fiscal_month_mmm <> 'JAN' 
           then 0
           end*/
           
            ) rcv
           where snd_gbc_region||'-'|| "AUN"  = rcv_attribute3) bat
           where not  exists (select 1 from ods_vw_gb_db_q.dsw_inv_hist hist
    
    where bat."Invoice Number" = hist.os_inv_num
    and bat."Invoice Item" = hist.os_inv_line_num

)
```

Above query is something I am looking to modify.

Comment: So the obvious question is whether view ods_vw_gb_db_q.dsw_inv_hist has a column named os_inv_num.